# Optimize logic of jQuery Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very illogical jQuery code and I want to see if someone finds a better way to do the exact same thing:

jQuery:

```
$(".col-md-3 img").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().children(".search").show();
    $(this).parent().children(".photo").css("opacity","0.4");
}, function(){
    $(this).parent().children(".search").hide();
    $(this).parent().children(".photo").css("opacity","1");
});
```

HTLM corresponding to this code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="photo" src="img/1_small.jpg" alt="img" />
    <img class="search hidden-xs" src="img/search.png" width="50px"/> 
</div>
```

I have multiple similar divs.

EDIT:

I don't like the fact that I am accessing the DOM many times with:

```
$(this).parent().children();
```

I'm going back and forth and I think it might be a better solution.

The problem with the siblings is that one image is on the other, with position absolute and this causes some errors on the jQuery. The live website you can see here: [live](http://florin-pop.com/work/Photo%20Gallery/)

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking for a code review rather than a specific answerable question that will be of use to future visitors.

Comment: you'll need to do a better job of explaining what is wrong with your current code if you want decent answers.

Comment: @FlorinPop, everyone seems to be confused about exactly what you think the problem is.  The answers so far address different possibilities, but maybe you could add to the question.

Comment: As @zzzzBov hinted, this question is better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @FlorinPop check my answer (with jQuery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use **CSS**, 0% jQuery:

```
.photo-wrap .search {display:none}
.photo-wrap .photo {opacity:1}

.photo-wrap:hover .search {display:inline-block}
.photo-wrap:hover .photo {opacity:.4}
```

```
<div class="col-md-3 photo-wrap">
    <img class="photo" src="img/1_small.jpg" alt="img" />
    <img class="search hidden-xs" src="img/search.png" width="50px"/> 
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cgyr2c9f/)**

With *jQuery*, you can get `.col-md-3` selector instead of `.col-md-3 img`:

```
$(".col-md-3").hover(function(){
    $(".search", this).show()
    $(".photo", this).fadeTo("fast", 0.4)
}, function(){
    $(".search", this).hide()
    $(".photo", this).fadeTo("fast", 1)            
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly what you don't like about the current code, but you could do this:

```
var hoverer = function(show, opacity) {
 return function() {
    $(this).parent().children(".search").toggle(show);
    $(this).parent().children(".photo").css("opacity", opacity);
 };
};

$(".col-md-3 img").hover(hoverer(true, "0.4"), hoverer(false, "1"))
```

Comment: I want to avoid: $(this).parent().children() DOM manipulation.